# Float values UNION ALL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, precision

I have two ms sql server tables with column of type float (not null).

when I do union ALL in those two tables

```
SELECT [float_column], 
       Min(sourcename) AS ExistsInFile 
FROM   (SELECT [float_column], 
               'File 1' AS SourceName 
        FROM   table1 
        WHERE  column1 = 'abc' 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT [float_column], 
               'File 2' AS SourceName 
        FROM   table2 
        WHERE  column1 = 'abc') x 
GROUP  BY [float_column] 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT sourcename) <> 2
```

it gave me following output, but it should not show any difference as both values are same.

```
float_Column     |    ExistsInFile
-53590187.62            File 2
-53590187.62            File 1
```

Is this because of float type? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Floats are approximate, they don't always store an exact value. This is why you should not rely on comparing them in a group by or where clause.

Comment: More info on using these datatypes in SQL Server: [Using decimal, float, and real](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the problem is the float.  The issue here is not the `union all`.  The issue is the `group by`.

Floating point numbers can differ the the smallest bits representing the number -- and you can't see the differences.  So, for your problem, just convert everything to a decimal:

```
SELECT CAST([float_column] as DECIMAL(12, 2), 
       Min(sourcename) AS ExistsInFile 
FROM   (SELECT [float_column], 
               'File 1' AS SourceName 
        FROM   table1 
        WHERE  column1 = 'abc' 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT [float_column], 
               'File 2' AS SourceName 
        FROM   table2 
        WHERE  column1 = 'abc') x 
GROUP BY CAST([float_column] as DECIMAL(12, 2) 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT sourcename) <> 2 ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it and mark as answer. Have a nice rest of the day!